# Create spreadsheet from text document with more than 1.2 million lines

Tags: excel, rows, data-import

I am trying to create a single Excel spreadsheet page from a text file with more than 1.2 million lines. However, Excel 2016 doesn't support more than 1048576 rows.

Is it possible to do this?

Comment: This is not a forum, and you should provide what research you have done, along with some more about your goal and some sample data. That said, you do have a reasonable question at the base so I have vastly reworded your question to be a more appropriate form.

Comment: @ti7 We know the OPs goal and they dont need to include sample data, did you even read the question? Its an excel row issue not a code issue? However i do agree with your statement about research

Comment: @connorg98 It is sometimes possible to reduce a problem with a little sample data (especially XY problems). Further, the user has obviously not read the guidelines from their question design, and there is limited space to welcome and help them create better questions in the future.

Comment: @ti7 I understood what the OP needed and personally i do not think sample data is necessary in this instance however i agree that they will never learn how to ask a good question without criticisms

Comment: Why don't you use MS-Access?

Answer (score 1):

This is currently the reason i dont use excel much anymore.

You can use excel still but you would have to spread the data over 2 tabs in excel;

- 500,000 rows on Sheet 1
- 700,000 rows on Sheet 2 and so on

To my knowledge you cannot change the max rows, i would recommend that you have a look around/google at other ways of showing the data like SQL for example because in my opinion Excel is outdated.

I hope this has helped, thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Oh! it is even good to know that we cannot change the max rows! Thanks, Connorg98!

Comment: No problem atall i hope it helped

Comment: If you are happy with my answer and it has helped you can you mark it as your favorite as i need the extra reputation :P thank you

Comment: lol... but the software delimit work for me better and the only problem is that how can I change those converted excel file to access because I need to do some relationship using create query design in access! thanks

Comment: Do you mean how to convert an excel file to microsoft access? If you do here is a quick guide http://smallbusiness.chron.com/convert-excel-documents-microsoft-access-40490.html :)

Comment: Hi sorry do you mean separate tabs? in excel

Comment: I think you will find your answer if you put up another question my friend :) it is no good asking on this question

Answer (score 0):

What is the purpose of having 1.2 million records in excel? If it is to do some kind of  analysis you will need to aggregate them anyhow.

As for your question: you can import a text file of 1.2 Mln records (with reasonable amount of fields)into excel using powerpivot.

Powerpivot/Manage
Get exernal data from other sources/text file